# AngularFire2 check if account exists

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using Ionic with AngularFire2 to authenticate against Firebase. I allow a user to login via a GooglePlus provider and create an account on Firebase. Then if the user logs out, and tries to log in with a Facebook account with same email address using a **browser**, they get the following messages:

```
loginFacebookBrowser(): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    return new Promise<FirebaseAuthState>((resolve) => {
        this.af.auth.login({ provider: AuthProviders.Facebook, method: AuthMethods.Popup }).then((success: FirebaseAuthState) => {
            resolve(success);
        }).catch((error) => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.error('loginFacebook', error);
            this.doAlert('loginFacebook: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
}
```

> tg {code: "auth/account-exists-with-different-credential", message:
>   "An account already exists with the same email addr…ng a provider
>   associated with this email address.", email: "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
>   credential: Uf, __zone_symbol__currentTask: t}

If I use the AngularFire cordova plugin and try login on an **Android device**, it just hangs with no error message.

```
loginFacebookCordova(): Promise<FirebaseAuthState> {
    return new Promise<FirebaseAuthState>((resolve) => {
        Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
            let cred: firebase.auth.AuthCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
            firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
                resolve(data);
            });
        }, error => {
            this.loading.dismiss();
            console.error('loginFacebook: ' + error);
            this.doAlert('loginFacebook: ' + error.message);
        });
    });
}
```

**Question**

How do I get the Cordova Plugin to have the same behavior as the browser, and display a meaningful message to the user? Or if this is not possible, is it possible to check if the account (email address) already exists with a different provider?

**package.json**

```
"angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
"firebase": "^3.7.5",
```

Comment: Apologies, the error was on my side. I was not catching the error correctly.

               firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(cred).then((data: FirebaseAuthState) => {
                    resolve(data);
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.loading.dismiss();
                    console.error('loginFacebook: ' + error);
                    this.doAlert('Login with Facebook: ' + error.message);
                });

Comment: FYI, firebase.js 3.9.0 now supports OAuth sign in for Cordova: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova